# Python encode/decode from JSON exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, json, unicode, character-encoding

I pulling in some JSON data that has something like this:

```
{
 "string":"â€¢ Christmas 2014 â€¢",
 "layer_id":490,
 "other": "attributes",
 "that_dont": "matter"
}
```

This JSON is being generated elsewhere and I'm pulling it in via an http request (using `json.loads(request.text)`).

When I print the string in my console, I get:

```
â˘ Christmas 2014
```

(and an exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError error if I try to str())

I'm printing the string on a PDF and need the string to literally be:

```
"\u00B7 Christmas 2014 \u00B7"
```

My instincts are a bit hacky and I just want to replace the series of strange characters with the proper unicode point, but I don't even know what it is that I'm looking to replace.

Comment: Why U+00B7 and not U+2022? That's the original content, in any case; `• Christmas 2014 •`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `response.text`; you are causing a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) here. `response.text` may end up using the wrong codec if no characterset was specified on the response.

Use `response.json()` instead, and let that handle the correct codec for your JSON.

If you *still* see the same result, then the source used cp1252 to decode UTF-8 data and you need to revert that process:

```
corrected = broken.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
```

which fixes your specific issue:

```
>>> print u"â€¢ Christmas 2014 â€¢".encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
• Christmas 2014 •
```

Those are [U+2022 BULLET](http://codepoints.net/U+2022) characters.

You could also use the [`ftfy` library](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy), which can handle Mojibake untangling automatically for you:

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> print ftfy.fix_text(u"â€¢ Christmas 2014 â€¢")
• Christmas 2014 •
```